Custom JSONResponse response for FastAPI - cannot access field in subclass
I want my FastAPI application to return JSON:API responses. It would be really cumbersome to craft each response manually so I've looked into creating a custom response class, one based on JSONResponse, since the responses have to be in JSON format.
They have an example here:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#custom-response-class
So, subclass your response class (in my case JSONResponse), subclass it, implement the render method.
So far so good:
class JSONAPIResponse(JSONResponse):

    def render(self, content: Any) -> Any:

        # Null object.
        if content is None:
    [...]


However, the problem comes at the next step.
If I add a content_object_type to JSONAPIResponse, I put it in the __init__ method and everything, FastAPI still complains about it.

class JSONAPIResponse(JSONResponse):

    content_object_type: str

    def __init__(self, content: Any, content_object_type: str):
        super().__init__(content=content)

        self.content_object_type = content_object_type

    def render(self, content: Any) -> Any:

        self.content_object_type

Elsewhere in the code base, another method that actually invokes JSONAPIResponse:
    return JSONAPIResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(content_object), content_object_type="bla")

Boom  this is the FastAPI error message below

def render(self, content: Any) -> Any:

  self.content_object_type

E       AttributeError: 'JSONAPIResponse' object has no attribute 'content_object_type'

So I've declared the attribute, I have it in the constructor that's used... what's wrong?

Can you provide more info about what you need to do, Im confused a little because the render() method should return json byte objects, here you are returning JSONAPIResponse

I had a line that was explaining that part, I've edited my description to clarify that the return is from elsewhere and it just shows how I'm invoking JSONAPIResponse. Hopefully the description is clearer, the return was just showing that I'm invoking the correct constructor.

in your JSONAPIResponse.__init__ after you set your content_object_type, can you print the __dict__ for test?
